# How to pass two php variables in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my code for fetching values from DB in a Table.
After fetching values I'm simply taking the ID of user in function to Activate and Deactivate that user.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registration";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $test['id'];
    $status = $test['status'];
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
    echo"<td><font color='black'>".$test['username']."</font></td>";
    echo"<td><font color='black'>".$test['firstname']." " .$test['lastname'] .
    "</font></td>";
    echo"<td><font color='black'>" . $test['status'] . "</font></td>";
    echo"<td><a id='link' onclick=\"activate(" . $id . ");\">Activate</a></td>";
    echo"<td><a id='link' onclick=\"deactivate(" . $id . ");\">Deactivate</a></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Now, this is my AJAX code for activate()

```
function activate(item)
{
    var id = item;

    if (confirm("Do you wants to Activate user"))
    {
        $("#wait").css("display", "block");
        var id = item;
        var status = status;

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/update_act.php?id=" + id + "&req=activate", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

I want to write or update the activate function so that,
I will get the current status of the user so that I'll check if the User is already Activated or not.
And if user is already Activated it should prompt me that this user is already activated else I should be able to Activate the User.

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: If you already have jQuery included in your project, then consider using `$.ajax` or `$.get` instead of native `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Two options : Pass the variable as GET parameters, and get them via JavaScript window.location(or something like that) - or simply render your JavaScript with PHP - i.e. <script> var param = <?php echo $variable ?> -- there's advanced ways to render .js via the .php interpreter if you look into it enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to pass $status in the function as well so you can do something as

**In Php code**

```
 echo '<td><a id="link" onclick="activate(\''.$id.'\',\''.$status.'\');">Activate</a></td>';
```

And you can change the JS function signature as

**In Javascript**

```
function activate(yourItem,uStatus){  }
```

Comment: Can you see ur source code in HTML and see if the data is passed in the calling method.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: check ur $id and $status has data and that of $status contains single quote

Comment: Please post what you see in the view source for that part, else its impossible to guess what is happening, and if you have data for both variables it should pass the data in the function as mentioned.

Comment: I'm getting this in source code<a id='link' onclick='activate(\''.1.'\',\''.PAID.'\');'>Activate</a></td>

Comment: Use the code I have added in my answer, reload it I have made an update and you should see the source as <a id="link" onclick="activate('1','PAID');">Activate</a>